# Multiplying arrays in Java without a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

Suppose I have two equally long arrays of numbers. I want to create a third array such that:

```
c[0] = a[0] * b[0]
c[1] = a[1] * b[1]
...
```

If I were in Matlab, I could write a loop that performed the multiplication like this:

```
for i=1:length(a)
c(i) = a(i) * b(i);
end
```

but I know that it's good to avoid for loops, and there's a way to do that, which is:

```
c = a .* b;
```

This makes sense to me, and having timed it (tic toc) several times on two 8192-length arrays of random numbers, the .* method consistently finishes about 3x faster than the for loop.

So now I want to multiply the arrays in Java. So I write a for loop and say:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
```

My question is: is there a better way of doing this that avoids the for loop? And if there is, does it make a difference? In my mind, it runs faster without the for loop because it's multiplying the numbers in parallel instead of in series, but I have no idea what's going on under the hood (like if the compiler is unrolling the loop on its own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two reasons why `.*` is faster than an explicit loop in Matlab. By *explicit* I mean a loop written in Matlab code, as opposed to *internal* loops that Matlab functions might be using. The reasons are:

- `.*` is [vectorized](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). This means that, although it very likely does the computations internally with a loop, that loop has been coded in [some faster language](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4333) than Matlab itself.
- `.*` is [multithreaded](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958-which-matlab-functions-benefit-from-multithreaded-computation), and so it benefits from multiple cores running in parallel.

So in Matlab, whenever there is a built-in vectorized function, you should use it.   Although the speed of Matlab's explicit loops has improved in recent years (thanks to JIT compiling for example), they are still slower than their vectorized versions.

Java follows a more conventional approach, in which explicit loops are the norm. They are not slow, and generally there are not vectorized functions that can replace them. So I'd say an explicit loop is the way to go in Java.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know anything about how Java handles these loops? Does it try to run some of the stuff in parallel?

Comment: @Adjwilley I don't know much about Java, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Although YOU are not writing a loop in Matlab, underneath, it's most likely that there is some kind of loop, and even maybe more than one (we'd have to check the source code). There is nothing magic in Matlab. It's just a "simplified" language, where underneath there are more complex code generated.

Your Java loop is the correct way.